# Visa processing period for 2 year family visa category

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, long-term

Planning to get my mother on 02 year family visa category to spend some time with my sons who are both born in the UK and british citizens... would like to know how long will it take for the visa to process...

Answer (score 2):

Processing times for visas vary according to the location where the application is made, the strength of the application, the number of other applications made at that location at that time, etc.

You can get an estimate for your particular case from the [UK Government web site](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y), which is currently giving estimates based on actual processing times for applications made in December 2018.

A quick look at a few random locations suggests that most visitor applications are decided in 15 to 30 days. Your mother's application could be quicker or slower than this.

Answer (score 0):

The family visa can take up to 3 months if it’s a settlement visa. I think it’s the worst one 
If you need more informations don’t hesitate

Comment: Welcome to the site. We appreciate your willingness to help but your answer is a bit too short and needs an explanation of how you know this. And it might be a different type of visa.